# Can I use Google Analytics with commercials from other networks?

Tags: google-analytics, advertising, statistics, affiliate, ctr

Does Google Analytics allow me to configure and evaluate statistics like CTR etc. for commercials from networks other than Google Adsense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [campaign variables](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55578), you can tag the contents of links in your advertisements. This will let you track the inbound performance of your advertising.

So, if you have a banner ad on Reddit for `example.com/reddit-sale`, you could use the link with something like.

> `http://example.com/reddit-sale/?utm_medium=banner&utm_source=reddit.com&utm_campaign=redditsale`

The traffic this gets would then be trackable within Google Analytics.

Google Analytics also has a feature for importing Google Adwords click and cost data. This is currently exclusive to Google Adwords, and cannot be directly replicated with other Ads platforms. So, there's no way to directly evaluate CTR and $ data for any other advertising platform within Google Analytics.

If your ad runs using an `<iframe>`, and your target site allows, you could put Google Analytics code in your ads to track impressions (I'd recommend using Event Tracking, as its more flexible and less confusing that muddling pageviews.), but I'd recommend using a different tracking account than your primary one, so the data doesn't ruin your primary data (each ad impression would count as a visit, and wouldn't make sense in the context of the rest of your data.)

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to create a landing or redirect page that includes the analytics code and then checkout the "goals" section under the profile of the site you wish to track.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be answering the question...